# lambda expression to simple c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i am trying to correct a code and I got stuck at a lambda expression.

```
addrow.Outcome1 = values.Where(row => DecompRowComparer(row, filterstring1))
                        .ToList()
                        .Sum(row => Convert.ToDouble(row[outcomeIndex]));
```

Can any help me to translate this expression into a simple c# code.

I want to check if row[outcomeIndex] has only only one letter or not, if it has only one letter and it is a .(dot) then I want to replace it with 0 , but I am not sure how to do this

row[outcomeIndex] can be numeric as well as a .(dot) and this line give error : Input string was not in a correct format. when the row[outcomeIndex] is a .(dot) , so how can I convert this line into simple way (multilines)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202438/discussion-on-question-by-mohammad-shahbaz-lambda-expression-to-simple-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple LINQ code. Converting it into a loop would be a lot more complex. `ToList()` is redundant here as `Sum` works with any IEnumerable.

Instead of using `Convert.ToDouble` use [double.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) which allows you control what happens if parsing fails.

`double.TryParse` returns true if it succeeds, false otherwise. The parsed double is returned as an out variable. You can combine that with the ternary operator to return the parsed value on success, or 0, or any other default value on failure.

The ternary operator `(condition)? trueExpression:falseExpression` checks the condition and returns the result of trueExpression if the condition is true, `falseExpression` if false.

Putting both together :

```
var value=double.TryParse(someString,out var result) ? result : 0;
```

If `someString` is `13` parsing succeeds and `result` is set to `13`. If it contains `.`, parsing fails and the second branch of the `?:` expression returns 0;

The query can be rewritten as :

```
addrow.Outcome1 = values.Where(row => DecompRowComparer(row, filterstring1))
                        .Sum(row=>double.TryParse(row[outcomeIndex],out var d)?d:0)
```

or

```
addrow.Outcome1 = values.Where(row => DecompRowComparer(row, filterstring1))
                        .Select(row=>row[outcomeIndex])
                        .Sum(input=>double.TryParse(input,out var d)?d:0)
```

Comment: it says var does not exist in current context

Comment: it says invalid expression term double, both double and var giving error

Comment: What version of VS? C#7 in order to do it

Comment: @MohammadShahbaz which Visual Studio version are you using? This code works as-is since C# 7. You'll have to use `out double` for older version

Comment: VS 2015, I have defined double d as global and removed double from your code then It is not showing error.

Comment: @MohammadShahbaz *no*, don't use a global. Use `out double`. Otherwise you'll end up summing the wrong values

Comment: yes, I saw that, it gave me wrong calculation, but when I use out double , it is showing error in code: Invalid expression term double

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't think `out double` will work for them as this is before you could create inline out variables.  It has to be `input => { double d; return double.TryParse(input,out d) ? d : 0;}`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code without using Linq

```
double sum = 0;
foreach(var row in values)
{
    if(DecompRowComparer(row, filterstring1))
    {
        sum += Convert.ToDouble(row[outcomeIndex])
    }
}

addrow.Outcome1 = sum;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am accepting other answer because it also explains what is wrong with the code in a lot more detail but you gave solution what I asked for..